# Limitation in Java HttpUrlConnection getting content length

Tags: java, download, httpurlconnection

Right so, I started my project on creating a Java download manager which is going nicely. The only problem I am seeing at the moment is when i request the content length of the URL. When i use the method provided by HttpUrlConnection's getContentLength, it returns an Int.

This is great if i was only to ever download files that were less than 2GB in file size. Doing some more digging and find that java does not support unsigned int values, but even so that would only give me a file size of a 4GB max.

Can anyone help me in the right direction of getting the content size of a file that is greater than 2GB.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for you answer Elite Gentleman, i tried what you suggested but that kept returning a null value, so instead what i did was

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) absoluteUrl.openConnection();
conn.connect();
long contentLength = Long.parseLong(conn.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));
```

For some reason just using conn.getRequestProperty always returned a null for me

Comment: I was looking for `getHeaderField(...)` but I couldn't find it. That's actually the BEST way of doing it....I've updated my answer.

Oh yeah, `getRequestProperty` is used BEFORE doing a POST/GET request, i.e. it's for a request and not a response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why not try use the headerField method for getting content length? i.e.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = new HttpURLConnection(...); 
long contentLength = Long.parseLong(connection.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));
```

It's equivalent as `connection.getContentLength` except that the return value is of type string. This can give accurate result of bit length.

**UPDATE:** I updated it to use HeaderField instead of requestProperty...thanks to the author of the question.

---

Thanks to @FlasH from Ru, you can achieve the same result using from JDK 7 and higher.

- [`URLConnection.getContentLengthLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong()).

This, in effect calls the new [`URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderFieldLong(java.lang.String,%20long)) method, which has also been introduced in JDK 7 and higher.

Comment: Btw, there's a `connection.getContentLengthLong` available now (since Java 7) which does the same as suggested but with a fewer words.

Comment: It seems this solution will trigger download also. how can we just get the header but not start actual download to save bandwidth?

Comment: For those seeking the Android equivalent... API 24 https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLengthLong()
Just do a manual get like the answer shows!