# Android HttpURLConnection content length

Tags: android, ios, httpconnection, content-length

I am trying to download files from a server in android and show progress dialog using code very similar to the [answer provided in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) but i am not able to get content length in `HttpURLConnection`'s `getContentLength()` method. Content length for all files is -1.

For the same file, i get correct content length in iOS app with `NSHTTPURLResponse`'s `expectedContentLength` method.

Is there some basic difference in the way these methods fetch the content length for an http connection/response?

**EDIT 1:**

Tried following few things as suggested some answers and comments.

1. Set `Accept-Encoding` header to `identity`
2. Fetching the content length as string (from header field `Content-Length`) and then converting it to long
3. Tried `conn.getContent().toString().length()` instead of `getContentLength()`

None of these worked for me yet.

What baffles me most is i get the content length in iOS but not on android.

**EDIT 2:**

Heres my iOS and Android code for comparison -

iOS:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:1200.0];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[connection start];
```

Android:

```
URL url = new URL(downloadUrlString);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection .setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
connection.connect();
```

The only difference i can see is caching. 
So i added following line in android code as well but nothing changed.

```
connection.setUseCaches(true);
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2294899/719212

Comment: @R4j i checked the link. I tried it but it did not work. Answer in that link is more valid for httprequests which return the correct content length but are too large for an int. I am not getting any content-lentgth.

Comment: Depending on the webserver, the protocol, the connection, or the method of downloading, `Content-length` may not always be available. But for your case, I think you should make a request like ios does (check your header, content type...). Or maybe you should provide your ios code then people can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause for this problem turned out to be Cookies.

I am using a web view in one of the activities in my application. Some cookies are stored by the web view. All other REST api and file download requests work without those cookies however for a particular type of requests, the cookies are necessary.

Apparently, android web view and the connection requests do not share cookies out of the box like iOS. As a result i had to make changes in my code to make sure that the HttpUrlConnection uses WebKit's cookie store. I did it using [method described in the accepted answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18057624/two-way-sync-for-cookies-between-httpurlconnection-java-net-cookiemanager-and).

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
   HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   conn .setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
   conn.connect();
```

Comment: Worked for me!!! In my case it was an issue with the server update, when server didn't send content-length header when encoding was gzip.

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to content length, can you try

```
  conn.getContent().toString().length()
```

where conn is the HttpURLConnection object

Comment: I get -1 as the content length with this approach as well.

Comment: this means there is no content length, I think your problem not in the content length. It is the way of connect. As you mentioned, you got the file by ISO and you read content. This means you forget to set something in the header before making connect or you set something wrong.